# Sideloading Outlook 360 add-in on Outlook main window

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

I want to side load Outlook add-in to Outlook main window. Just like Nutshell add-in in below screen shot. I looked at the ExtensionPoint help, but there is no extension points available which can show add-in like below. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MessageReadCommandSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#messagereadcommandsurface) extension point will provide you with this view. As you may notice, to invoke the "Nutshell" add-on the app's icon is above "read message" view.

Comment: As OfficeJS add-ons work with single item, extension points are tight to "read" or "compose" windows. There is one more [Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#module) extension, but it's only availabe for desktop Outlook.

Comment: I tried with MessageReadCommandSurface extension but add-in icon is not visible in reading pane of Outlook window. Its only visible if I open any email in separate window.

Comment: @NileshShinde If message selected in Explorer view the icon will be visible above the message content, similar to screenshot you have provided. I you still have the problem, I suggest to create another question and provide your manifest.xml file in it. Best regards.